# VBA : Seeking solution regarding the Confirmation Msg box pop-up again after the searched record being deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform which has a search function, upon user search the record and it will be show in the user form.  User could deleted the "found" record by clicking the "Delete" button.

Before the record be deleted, a confirmation msgbox pops up and once user click "Yes", the record will be deleted and Userform is reset as all cells blank. Follow by this, another Msgbox "Your record has been removed from your record" pops up as information.

My code as below:

```
Private Sub Img_Delete_click()
    
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("My Form")
    sh.Unprotect ""
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    X = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
                                        
        For Y = 16 To X
        If Sheets("My Form").Cells(Y, 12).Value = txt_Search.Text Then
                
            If MsgBox("Do you want to delete this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
            sh.Unprotect ""
            Rows(Y).Delete
            Else
            Exit Sub
            End If
                  
        Call Reset_all
         
        MsgBox "Your record has been removed from the form.", vbInformation, "Record deleted"
        txt_name.SetFocus
        
        sh.Protect ""
        
        End If
        Next

End Sub
```

My problem is : Whilst I run the code for deletion and after the record has been deleted, the confirmation Msgbox with "Yes" or "No" pops up again.  Is there anyone could figure me out the problem in my code?

Comment: You are looping over all records to search for the entered text. If a record was found and deleted, the loop continues (Note it will skip the next row because you delete one row, so that's another flaw). Either your search text appears another time or, when you call the reset routine, you reset also the search text. If you are sure that the search text is present only once, put an `Exit For` after you deleted the row (last statement before `End If`)

Comment: yes!!! It works fantastic after I put an `Exit For` before the last `End If`.  Thanks for your kind assistance.......^0^

However, I still have problem in my other codes......May I humbly seek your assistance again?

Comment: @FunThomas, Hi Thomas! I've post another question, may I seek your professional advice as well?
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76761349/vba-problem-seek-assistance-from-my-vba-code-mysearch-result-msgbox-is-not>