# my "Search result Msgbox" is not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

In my Userform, User could enter text for search.  If record existed, record will appears in the userform for user to delete or update by using clicking the button.  Else, a msgbox "No record match from your list" pops up.

My codes as below refer.

However, after I input text and click the "Search" button, the msgbox pops up always (sometimes it pops up several times) with no record found, even the record I search is factually existed in the excel.

May I know what's the problem? and how should I refine my code?

```
Private Sub Img_Search_click()

    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    X = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
                
        For Y = 16 To X
                       
        If Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 12).Value = txt_Search.Text Then
        txt_name = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 7).Value
        cmb_Type = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 11).Value
        txt_Inventory = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 12).Value
        txt_CardReader = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 13).Value
        txt_Function = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 14).Value
        txt_OLocation = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 15).Value
        txt_OPort = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 16).Value
        txt_NLocation = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 17).Value
        txt_NPort = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 18).Value
        txt_Printer = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 19).Value
        cmb_Printer_Network = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 20).Value
        txt_Remarks = Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 21).Value
        
        Else
        MsgBox "No record match from your request list.", vbInformation, "Information"
                
        End If
        Next
        End Sub
```

I've also try to refine the code as below to replace the `Else` part, but the "search" even not work!

```
        if Sheets("myForm").Cells(Y, 12).Value <> txt_Search.Text Then
        MsgBox "No record match from your request list.", vbInformation, "Information"
        Me.txt_Search.Value = ""
        txt_name.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        end if
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be several records that can be found with the search criteria? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with `For Y = 16 to X`

Comment: Y is dim for Row, X is dim for the last row according to user's input.  The list will be updated so the search range will be a dynamic area.  16 is the 1st row is the dynamic area.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: are there supposed to be several matches to the search term or is it just "user tries to find <term> -> find <term> in list -> show values" ? Because you could just search for that <term> in the L-column and work from there without a for-loop. If you need multiple matches, then you're currently overwriting those values.

Comment: No several matches.  Actually, users could only input the S/N that contains in excel (previous record added by users).  This no. is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments: a for-loop isn't necessary in your case where there's only going to be one match possible. A Application.Match is enough to get the correct row and get your values this way:

```
Private Sub Img_Search_click()

    Dim X, arr, lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    'Dim txt_name, cmb_Type, txt_Inventory, txt_CardReader, txt_Function, txt_OLocation
    'Dim txt_Oport, txt_NLocation, txt_NPort, txt_Printer, cmb_Printer_Network, txt_Remarks
                
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myForm")
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    X = Application.Match(txt_Search.Text, rng, 0) + 1
    If Not IsError(X) Then
        arr = ws.Range(Cells(X, 1), Cells(X, 21)).Value
        txt_name = arr(1, 7)
        cmb_Type = arr(1, 11)
        txt_Inventory = arr(1, 12)
        txt_CardReader = arr(1, 13)
        txt_Function = arr(1, 14)
        txt_OLocation = arr(1, 15)
        txt_Oport = arr(1, 16)
        txt_NLocation = arr(1, 17)
        txt_NPort = arr(1, 18)
        txt_Printer = arr(1, 19)
        cmb_Printer_Network = arr(1, 20)
        txt_Remarks = arr(1, 21)
    Else
        MsgBox "No record match from your request list.", vbInformation, "Information"
    End If
End Sub
```

The commented-out lines are because I didn't want to flesh out an entire Form. Used an array to minimize the interaction with the sheet. No more for-loop and only one MsgBox when it isn't found :)

Comment: I ve tried your code. I just change the below :

lRow = X = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

(Coz my record may have some blank cells in each row)

but it can't work and have error on this line. 

X = Application.Match(txt_Search.Text, rng, 0) + 1

What can I do ? T0T

Comment: The rows at the end of your data that don't have a value in your A-column (which your checking with) don't matter, right? Because either they have a matching value in that column or they don't (and then won't match). Just use the lRow as I have it in my code. (the rest of your columns don't matter to find the last row in the A-column).

Comment: Yeah.....I finally make it with your codes !! Thousands thank for our kind assistance !!! Thanks .....Thanks ....Thanks..... ^0^

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over every row from 16 up to `Y` and checking if the values match - If they don't you show the MsgBox.

So let's say the match is in row 20 - `Y` will be 20 and you'll start your Loop with `X = 16`
Row 16 doesn't match so the MsgBox is triggered.
Row 17 doesn't match so the MsgBox is triggered
Row 18 doesn't match so the MsgBox is triggered
I think you get the point.

If you try to do a search function with a loop you shouldn't trigger the fail message as part of the loop (rather after the loop/ the search function has ended)

Comment: thanks for your advice.  I'm very green from writing VBA.  Is that means I need to put the "fail msg code" between <next> and <end Sub> instead in the part of loop?

I've try it. The msgbox pops up always in all circumstances even the record is existed in excel.  How could I do? Thanks again.

Comment: I finally make it ! Yeah ! Thanks for your assistance ! ^0^